# Generics: Mark type parameter as interface, so that other type parameter can extend it

Tags: java, generics

I have this class definition as a part of an Entity framework for my project:

```
public abstract class EntityManager<E, I extends EntityImpl<E, I, D> & E, D>
```

- `E` is an interface defining the functionality of an Entity and the class API users will use.
- `I` is the concrete implementation of that interface.
- `D` a data class for internal persistence logic

A normal implementation of an Entity usually looks like this:

```
public class PermissionImpl extends EntityImpl<Permission,PermissionImpl,PermissionData> implements Permission
```

The problem is that the `EntityManager` definition doesn't work since the second type parameter in an `&` structure can only be an interface and not  a class. In my case, `E` is *always* an interface.

How can I tell Java to only accept interfaces as `E` so that the error goes away?

Comment: Have you tried constraining E? For example, E extends InterfaceThatAllEntitiesImplement ?

Comment: @Rob Yap, created an `Entity` super interface and changed the generic parameter to `E extends Entity`, still the same, sadly.

Comment: Do you really need to pass the implementation of a e.g. `Permission` as a generic?

Comment: What is the use of knowing the implementation of `E`?